# Number of specific documents and greater

Tags: r, quanteda

From quanteda

I use this option to make a dfm

```
library(quanteda)

df <- data.frame(text = c("only a small text","only a small text","only a small text","only a small text","only a small text","only a small text","remove this word lower frequency"))
tdfm <- df$text %>%
  tokens(remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE) %>%
  dfm()
```

How is it possible to set also that I want to keep the most frequent words that exist in more than 6 documents? Every row is a document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dfm_keep` in combination with `docfreq` gives what you are looking for. I chose to select more than 5 so it works on your example. Otherwise the dfm would be empty.

```
dfm_keep(tdfm, pattern = featnames(tdfm)[docfreq(tdfm) > 5])
Document-feature matrix of: 7 documents, 4 features (14.3% sparse).
       features
docs    only a small text
  text1    1 1     1    1
  text2    1 1     1    1
  text3    1 1     1    1
  text4    1 1     1    1
  text5    1 1     1    1
  text6    1 1     1    1
  text7    0 0     0    0
```

Comment: thank you, so the same solution could it be also for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63038501/find-in-how-many-docs-occur-after-a-frq-step ?

Comment: Yes, same principle.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to use the `dfm_trim()` argument with `min_docfreq = 6`.  Using v2.1.0 after running your code above:

```
> dfm_trim(tdfm, min_docfreq = 6) %>%
      print(max_ndoc = -1)
Document-feature matrix of: 7 documents, 4 features (14.3% sparse).
       features
docs    only a small text
  text1    1 1     1    1
  text2    1 1     1    1
  text3    1 1     1    1
  text4    1 1     1    1
  text5    1 1     1    1
  text6    1 1     1    1
  text7    0 0     0    0
```